# массовая замена символов в mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица, в ней поле msg, там хранятся тексты наподобие:

```
привет ##как дела##
```

Мне нужно во всех полях msg заменить ## на №№.

Как это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)**, **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, mysql?

Comment: @Visman в вопросе php стоит, так что

Comment: Зачем php, если запросом mysql все заменить можно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить такой запрос в базе

```
UPDATE `your_table` SET `msg` = replace(`msg`, '##', '№№');
```

P.S. Про бэкап не забудьте.

Comment: Может стоит что-то с регуляркой упомянуть? А то вдруг там где-то  эти двойные диезы попадаются тоже?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, напишите свой ответ ;)